# Serve streaming video in Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, webapp2

I'm building a small educational web application. Along with other features like discussion forums, registered users will be able to view streaming videos. I'll be using Google App Engine's webapp2 framework for back-end development (with python). I want to specifically ask that how can I integrate video streaming into my application? I'm fairly new to web development and have a basic working knowledge of App Engine. I'll be using Google's Datastore to store all the app's data, but where do I store my videos that the app serves to users? I don't want to make the video content publicly available (e.g. YouTube), so what's the way to go?

I'm aware that GAE's Blobstore is dedicated to serving large files (e.g. videos) so will it be appropriate for this purpose? What are some other options?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Blobstore is fine. You can also use [Google Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/googlecloudstorageclient/), either directly or [through the Blobstore API](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/#Python_Using_the_Blobstore_API_with_Google_Cloud_Storage)

Plenty of related Q&As to study, many contain code snippets: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[google-app-engine]+video+streaming
.